# Does tf.train.latest_checkpoint() inherit the model name from tf.train.import_meta_graph()

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

In the case I have the following code:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('../logs/model-2.meta')
new_saver.restore(restored_sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../logs/'))
```

and in my ../logs/ file I have two models : model-1 and model-2

would TF automatically get the latest checkpoint from model-2 given that it was specified within import_meta_graph.

Would it be better to save different models in separate folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the model name with the saver to use separate name for different models `saver.save(sess, 'model_name', global_step=epoch_number)`. for a folder only one `checkpoint` file is saved. That keeps the information about the latest model to be used by the `tf.train.latest_checkpoint`.

So for different model it's always good to use separate folders.